# Calculate the value of K in the matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

If the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ K & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $A(A^3+3I)=2I$ then value of K is:

Answer: 1

Attempt: I thought of calculating polonium, and showing that the matrix is invertible and calculating the inverse knowing that $p(A) = 0$. Could you give me any suggestions?

Comment: why not just brute force it using the matrix of $A$ in the formula?

Comment: @Tortar I think this would be a lot of work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of that matrix is $z^2+z-2K$. This should be a divisor of $z(z^3+3)-2 = z^4+3z-2$. Now,
$$
z^4+3z-2 = (z^2-z+2)(z^2+z-1).
$$
Thus, $K = \tfrac 12$.